# When to use Future[T] vs. Future[Try[T]] when the call might fail

Tags: scala

I am slightly confused when to use which because futures are allowed to fail.  If futures are allowed to fail, then to me, that sounds like a `Try[]` in itself.

And if the `Try[]` is wrapped inside a Future, then what is the difference with a regular `Future[]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's really no reason to ever use a `Future[Try[T]]`.  You add no benefit over a plain `Future`, and a good deal of complexity.  `Trys` are sort of the synchronous version of `Futures`.  You use them to wrap operations you are blocking on that might fail, or potentially-failing operations that are lazily evaluated.  `Futures` are for when you need asynchronous semantics as well.

Comment: That's not entirely true. The semantics isn't the same.
If you use a plain `Future`, you can use the `recoverWith` method to handle a possible error of a Future execution. But `Future[Try[T]]` make it more obvious for the caller to handle errors returning from the async execution.

Comment: A function that returns Future[Try[T]] tells me there's a possible failure there that I have to handle. A Future[T] tells me much less, so I have to either write a recover for all Futures I encounter, or look into the function code to see if a failure is actually expected. Sure, a Future always has the potential to fail, but some functions expect failures and others don't and I don't like hiding that information.

Answer (score 0):

As Karl already answered, in your case there is no reason to use `Future[Try[T]]`, though in some cases `Future[Try[T]]` might be useful.

Example:
when you need to do multiple requests but if some of them fails you still want to keep other results

Here when one request fails, you dont get any results:

```
val requests = dataList.map(requestToBackend)
//collect all results with sequence
val results = Future.sequence(requests)
```

Other solution is to recover with try and then collect only successful results

```
val requests = dataList.map{ data =>
  requestToBackend(data)
    .map(Success)
    .recover { case x => Failure(x) }
}
//collect all results with sequence
val results = Future.sequence(requests).collect{ case Success(value) => value }
```